# How to use boost::pool library to create a custom memory allocator

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, allocator, boost-pool

I am new to boost and I want to know how exactly the boost::pool libraries can help me in creating a custom memory allocator.
And I have two vector of struct objects.
First vector is of structure type A, while second vector is of structure type B.
How can I reuse the memory allocated to the first vector to the second vector.

Answer (score 16):

Boost Pool is a library that defines a few allocator types.

Obviously, the focus of the library is to provide Pool Allocators.

Pool Allocators shine when you allocate objects of identical size.

> **Note** If your structure `A` and structure `B` aren't identical/very similar size you may not like this design assumption.

The allocators provided by the framework work with singleton pools, and they differentiate on the size of your container value_type. That's a bit inflexible if you want to reuse or even share the pool between different value-types. Also, singleton pools can be inflexible and imply thread-safety costs.

So, I wanted to see whether I could whip up the simplest allocator that alleviates some of these issues.

I used the source to `boost::pool_alloc` and the [cppreference example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) as inspiration, and then did some testing and memory profiling.

### A More Flexible Stateful Allocator

Here's the simplest pool allocator I could think of:

```
using Pool = boost::pool<boost::default_user_allocator_malloc_free>;

template <typename T> struct my_pool_alloc {
    using value_type = T;

    my_pool_alloc(Pool& pool) : _pool(pool) {
        assert(pool_size() >= sizeof(T));
    }

    template <typename U>
    my_pool_alloc(my_pool_alloc<U> const& other) : _pool(other._pool) {
        assert(pool_size() >= sizeof(T));
    }

    T *allocate(const size_t n) {
        T* ret = static_cast<T*>(_pool.ordered_malloc(n));
        if (!ret && n) throw std::bad_alloc();
        return ret;
    }

    void deallocate(T* ptr, const size_t n) {
        if (ptr && n) _pool.ordered_free(ptr, n);
    }

    // for comparing
    size_t pool_size() const { return _pool.get_requested_size(); }

  private:
    Pool& _pool;
};

template <class T, class U> bool operator==(const my_pool_alloc<T> &a, const my_pool_alloc<U> &b) { return a.pool_size()==b.pool_size(); }
template <class T, class U> bool operator!=(const my_pool_alloc<T> &a, const my_pool_alloc<U> &b) { return a.pool_size()!=b.pool_size(); }
```

Notes:

- This allocator is stateful, and thus requires container implementations that allow them (such as Boost Container, Boost MultiIndex). In theory, all C++11-compliant standard libraries [should also support them](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator)
- The comparisons should guide the containers to swap/copy the allocator or not. This is not an area I've though much about and the chosen approach to mark all pools of different requested-sizes different might be inadequate for some.

### Sample, Tests

On my compilers it works for both `std::vector` and Boost's `vector`:

- **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ed3514e0e885e01)</kbd>** - with GCC std::vector
- **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc0ffbce6ccdaac0)</kbd>** - with GCC boost::container::vector
- **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f7e8dbe5ab66ba3)</kbd>** - with Clang std::vector
- **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10d9607ab0608f8f)</kbd>** - with Clang boost::container::vector

All runs are leak-free and ubsan/asan clean.

> Note how we re-use the same pool with different containers of different struct sizes, and how we can even use it with multiple live containers at a time, provided that the element types fit in the request size (32)

```
struct A { char data[7];  };
struct B { char data[29]; };

int main() {
    //using boost::container::vector;
    using std::vector;

    Pool pool(32); // 32 should fit both sizeof(A) and sizeof(B)
    {
        vector<A, my_pool_alloc<A> > v(1024, pool);
        v.resize(20480);
    };

    // pool.release_memory();

    {
        vector<B, my_pool_alloc<B> > v(1024, pool);
        v.resize(20480);
    }

    // pool.release_memory();

    // sharing the pool between multiple live containers
    {
        vector<A, my_pool_alloc<A> > v(512, pool);
        vector<B, my_pool_alloc<B> > w(512, pool);
        v.resize(10240);
        w.resize(10240);
    };
}
```

### Profiling

Using Valgrind's Memory profiler shows, with the `release_memory` lines commented out as shown:

[image]

When commenting **in** the `release_memory()` calls:

[image]

I hope this looks like the thing you wanted.

### Further Ideas: Simple Segregated Storage

This allocator uses the existing `pool` which delegate back to malloc/free to allocate memory on demand. To use it with a fixed "realm", you might prefer using `simple_segregated_storage` directly. This article looks like a good starter https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.pool